# why does kubernetes networkPolicy delays the request

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I have a networkPolicy attached to a pod that looks like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: api-egress
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: 
  egress:
    - ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 3306
      to:
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 10.100.100.199/32
    - ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 443
      to:
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 10.100.100.198/32
    - ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 6379
      to:
        - podSelector:
            matchLabels:
              app: redis
    - ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 5672
      to:
        - podSelector:
            matchLabels:
              app.kubernetes.io/instance: queue
    - ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 8118
      to:
        - podSelector:
            matchLabels:
              app: support
    - ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 8000
      to:
        - podSelector:
            matchLabels:
              app: ocket
  policyTypes:
    - Egress
```

When the network policy is applied I can see on the application side that there is a delay of 2.5minutes in one auth request to the api while if it's not there the same request is finished in 861ms.

Anyone can explain why is this delay there and how can I improve it?

Comment: What rule causes you such a high delay?

Comment: I had only one rule. The one in the post. I did not had time to split it down to multiple little rules to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: Try splitting the network policy to figure out which of the 6 rules causes the issue